# SQL: Combining results

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM `restaurants` WHERE name LIKE '%string%'

SELECT * FROM `restaurants` WHERE address LIKE '%string%'

SELECT * FROM `menu_items` WHERE name LIKE '%string%'
```

I have these queries.

At the moment i show each query result seperatly. I would like to combine them all.

And all the results should have aliases with where they come from.
Example when it show a item/row from menu_items you should be able to see in the column "Type" that it is a 'item'.

And 'address' for the restaurants address results and 'name' for the restaurants name results.

in MySQL

How can i do this?

My final output should look like this: You search after "s"

```
Spagetti - item
Sonus Suni - restaurant
Sunssisway 1232 - restaurant address
Delicous Spaga - item
```

So i would need to create my own alias column.. 'item' AS 'Type' etc..

Comment: Which otput format you want to see?

Comment: see my little update hope that was what you meant

Comment: see my updated answer, you'll get the same only in one row per restaraunt/item. I would suggest to format final output in the application rather than DB in such case(you can use PIVOT to switch columns to rows but I believe this is not applicable for this particular business case)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine tables with different columns, you have to specify which columns you want.

```
SELECT
    'Name' AS Type,
    Id AS R_Id,
    NULL AS I_Id,
    Name,
    Address,
    NULL AS M_Id
FROM Restaurants
WHERE Name LIKE '%string%'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Address' AS Type,
    Id AS R_Id,
    NULL AS I_Id,
    Name,
    Address,
    NULL AS M_Id
FROM Restaurants
WHERE Address LIKE '%string%'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    'Item' AS Type,
    NULL AS R_Id,
    Id AS I_Id,
    Name,
    NULL AS Address,
    M_Id
FROM Menu_Items
WHERE Name LIKE '%string%'
```

Comment: +1 for the idea of supplying the name of the restaurant to the address, as well as supplying IDs (PKs) of the items found. Only one question: what is `Menu_Items.M_Id` and how is it different from `Menu_Items.Id`? (Well, it sounds like two questions, actually.)

Answer (score 1):

If all three tables has the same number of columns you can use [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html):

```
SELECT * FROM `restaurants` WHERE name LIKE '%string%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `restaurants` WHERE address LIKE '%string%'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM `menu_items` WHERE name LIKE '%string%'
```

**!!!Important:**

> The column names from the first SELECT statement are used as the
>   column names for the results returned. Selected columns listed in
>   corresponding positions of each SELECT statement should have the same
>   data type. (For example, the first column selected by the first
>   statement should have the same type as the first column selected by
>   the other statements.)
>
> If the data types of corresponding SELECT columns do not match, the
>   types and lengths of the columns in the UNION result take into account
>   the values retrieved by all of the SELECT statements.

For more details with examples see official [MySQL Documentation on UNION statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

**EDIT: Update**

If `menu_items` table has FK on `restaraunts` table you can join both tables and select consolidated output data, for instance:

```
SELECT r.*, mi.*
FROM restaurants r 
INNER JOIN menu m ON m.R_ID = r.ID
INNER JOIN menu_items mi ON m.ID = mi.M_ID
WHERE r.name LIKE '%string%' 
  AND r.address LIKE '%string%'
  AND mi.name LIKE '%string%'
```

Comment: They dont have same numbers of columns,

Comment: Doesm menu_items has reference to restaraunts table? Something like RestarauntId?

Comment: No they have references to menuId which then has references to the restaurant.

Comment: menuId references to a separate table `menu`? Please elaborate in which table menuId declared and how is referenced to an other table

Comment: in ´menu_items´ theres a ´m_id´ which references to the table ´menu´s ´id´. The ´menu´ has a column r_id , <- that you look for, which is referenced to the restaurants id

Comment: @Karem : see updated query, you can specify any set of columns from menu/menu_item/restaraunt in SELECT, I believe you know how to do it referencing column aliases r, m, mi

Comment: This is not working properly. Or not how I wish. It only show results if e.g "string" exists in the columns item name, address and name.
I wish to make this like a intelligent search thing, so you can search multiple places in one search field. So if you search after a item name, the item name should not match the restaurants name/address

Comment: To include all items even without matching enries in another tables you can replace INNER JOIN by LEFT JOIN, the point regarding name matching is not clear for me